# Error, when passing correct type to function in React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, static

I have problem, when i passing string variable to function.

I created interface MyMessageProps, which declare message on string,

later function MyMessage use this interface and return  with this message.

When i adding React Component and trying add this function to button onClick error appear.

```
interface MyMessageProps {
  message: string;
}

function MyMessage({ message }: MyMessageProps) {
  return <div>i shall speak! my message is: {message}</div>;
}

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    const variable = 'test';

    return (
      <div>
            <button onClick = {() => MyMessage(variable)}></button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const variable = {message: 'test'}` instead?  That's what the error message implies, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is expecting an object like:

```
const mssg = {
  message: 'MyMessage'
}
```

Try this:

```
interface MyMessageProps {
  message: string;
}

function MyMessage({ message }: MyMessageProps) {
  return <div>i shall speak! my message is: {message}</div>;
}

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    const variable = {
        message: 'my test'
     };

    return (
      <div>
            <button onClick = {() => MyMessage(variable)}></button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```